# How to clean url when using get method

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have a single product.php page that displays the data of each individual product on the products.php page

I am looking for a way to clean up the URL of each item that has it's data displayed through the product.php file.

current URL 'rubberholds/product.php?item=item1'

desired URL 'rubberholds/product/product-one' for example

products.php

```
<?php foreach ($limestoneItems as $item => $limestone): ?>    

<a href="product.php?item=<?php echo $item; ?>">
<img 
    src="assets/img/limestone/<?php echo $limestone[img]; ?>.jpg" 
    alt="<?php echo $limestone[alt]; ?>">
</a>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

product.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['item'])) {    
    $limestoneProduct = $_GET['item'];
    $product = $limestoneItems[$limestoneProduct];
  }
?>
```

Array

```
$limestoneItems = array(
  "item1" => array(
    title => "Product-One",
    img => "product1",
    alt => "Product1"                  
  )
);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? I want to remove .php extensions and replace '?item=item1' with $limestone[title]

EDIT

I have created a .htaccess file with the following code which is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) product.php?item=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You have to use .htaccess or something like that.

Comment: Modify `products.php` to output the links in the desired format. If you want to receive the value as a GET parameter, then you will need to configure some URL rewriting accordingly. (If you actually want to use `/product.php/product-one`, you can get the value from the PATH_INFO directly though, assuming that is not explicitly disabled in your server.) And since you are not using the array key any more as the identifier for your product, you will also have to modify your code that gets the product from that array, you will need to search it by its `title`.

Comment: Is `rubberholds` another URL-path segment? (Or the _hostname_?) Where is the `.htaccess` file in your file structure? (Or where would you like the `.htaccess` file to go?)

Comment: rubberholds is the root folder inside htdocs. My .htaccess file is currently inside this root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `rubberholds/product` - [Test here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=33070ab7-97ec-55d7-a377-09d4521da7b2)
- `rubberholds/product/product-one` - [Test here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=527b11d0-7ccb-59f4-b785-e25e7713533d)

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^rubberholds/product/?(.*)$ rubberholds/product.php?item=$1 [QSA]
```

---

Test data :

```
$limestoneItems = [
    'item1' => [
        'title' => 'Product-One',
        'img'   => 'product1',
        'alt'   => 'Product1',
    ],
    'item2' => [
        'title' => 'Product-Two',
        'img'   => 'product2',
        'alt'   => 'Product2',
    ],
    'item3' => [
        'title' => 'Product-Three',
        'img'   => 'product3',
        'alt'   => 'Product3',
    ],
];
```

**product.php**

```php
$title = strtolower($_GET['item']);
$data  = array_filter($limestoneItems, function ($v) use ($title) {
    $v['title'] = strtolower($v['title']);

    return in_array($title, $v);
});

if ($data) {
    $key     = array_keys($data)[0];
    $product = $limestoneItems[$key];

    var_dump($product); // Data found
} else {
    var_dump('Not found'); // Data not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may follow the bellow steps:

1) changes in .htaccess file to accept file without .php extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

2) products.php

```
<?php 
$limestoneItems = array(
  "item1" => array(
    "title" => "Product-One",
    "img" => "product1",
    "alt" => "Product1"                  
  )
);

foreach ($limestoneItems as $item => $limestone) {
    echo '
<a href="product?item='.$limestone[title].'">
<img src="assets/img/limestone/'.$limestone[img].'.jpg" alt="'.$limestone[alt].'">
</a>';
}
?>
```

3) product.php

```
<?php
$limestoneItems = array(
  "item1" => array(
    "title" => "Product-One",
    "img" => "product1",
    "alt" => "Product1"                  
  )
);

if (isset($_GET['item'])) { 
    $limestoneProduct = $_GET['item'];
    foreach ($limestoneItems as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['title'] === $limestoneProduct) {
            $product = $limestoneItems[$key];
            echo implode(" ",$product);  
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess file

> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\product-([^/]*)$
>   rubberholds/product.php?item=item1[L]

In your code change products.php

```
<a href='product.php/product-<?php echo $item; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given URL with the following format:

```
http://example.org/rubberholds/product.php?item=item1
```

Will result in the following format:

```
http://example.org/product/item1
```

Use the following Rewrite Rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /rubberholds/product.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below steps:

(1) Changes in .htaccess file to accept file without .php extension and with the change, you want in URL.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
#Below line will perform /product(any_file_name) as product.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
#Below line will perform /product/product-one(any_product_name) as product.php?item=product-one
RewriteRule ^product/([a-z0-9-]+) product.php?item=$1 [NC]
```

for more details on how to write url rules in .htaccess, please visit:
http://www.wbcsoftwarelab.com/wbcblog/url-rewriting-examples-using-htaccess

(2) product.php
While displaying products change url format
from:

```
<a href="product.php?item=<?php echo $item; ?>">
```

to:

```
<a href="product/<?php echo $limestone[title]; ?>">
```

(3) product.php
When user clicks on that url, you will get the product name in $_GET["item"] and use it like below to get its key:

```
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    if (isset($_GET['item'])) { 
        $product = $_GET['item'];
        foreach ($limestoneItems as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['title'] === $product) {
                $item = $key; //here you will get the item number for the product
                $productDetails = $value; //this will be details of the item
                echo "Item: ".$item."\n";
                echo "Product Details: " . implode(" ", $productDetails);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also you can visit http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all, and you can see the details on regexp used in .htaccess rules.